# Pass 2d array to subroutine as 1d argument fortran

Tags: arrays, arguments, fortran

I want to pass a 2d array to a subroutine and treat this array as a 1d argument. I tried to pass it in this way: subroutine(array(1,:)). This works if I define the arrays explicitly. However, if the arrays are allocatable, I get the following error: Actual argument for 'array' must be ALLOCATABLE
How can I make this work?

Here is some short sample code, which gives the error above:

```
program array
implicit none
integer,dimension(:,:),allocatable::i

allocate(i(2,2))
i(1,1)=1

call array_method(i(1,:))

contains

subroutine array_method(i)
implicit none
integer,allocatable,dimension(:),intent(in)::i
write(*,*) i(1)
end subroutine array_method

end program array
```

If I change code to explicitly defined arrays, like below, it works. However, I want to do it with allocatable arrays.

```
program array
implicit none
integer,dimension(2,2)::i

i(1,1)=1

call array_method(i(1,:))

contains

subroutine array_method(i)
implicit none
integer,dimension(2),intent(in)::i
write(*,*) i(1)
end subroutine array_method

end program array
```

If I change the argument array in the subroutine to allocatable and leave the passed argument in the main program as explicitly defined array (for example (2,2)), I still get the same error.

Comment: thanks francescalus for your answer, i updated my question

Comment: review the answer again, you can use `allocatable` in the main program, just don't specify it in the subroutine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the subroutine `array_method` (first one), you give the `allocatable` attribute to the dummy argument.  This requires that the actual argument also has that attribute.

However, the actual argument is `i(1,:)` which is *not* allocatable, even though `i` itself is.

Now, depending on what you want to do in the first case, the dummy argument doesn't need to have the `allocatable` attribute.  Unless you want to change the allocation status (which you can't given `intent(in)`), or use the "real" bounds of `i`, you can do without it.